# TypeScript issue in VUE 3 dynamic component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I has two VUE 3 components:

**Child.vue**

```js
<script lang='ts' setup>
//....some code

const emit = defineEmits<{
    (e: 'formErrors', errors: ValidationErrorsType): void,
    (e: 'formSuccess', success: boolean):void
}>()

//....some code

const submit = () => {
    //....some code
    //after validating form if it has errors, I am emitting them from component to parent
    emit('formErrors', errors);
}
</script>
.........more code here
```

**Parent.vue**

```js
<script lang='ts' setup>
const formErrors = ref<ValidationErrorsType>({});
const setFormErrors = (errors: ValidationErrorsType) => {
    formErrors.value = errors
}
</script>

<template>
    <component :is='Child' @form-errors='setFormErrors'/>
</template>
```

**In this case I am getting error:**
[vue-tsc] Type '(errors: ValidationErrorsType) => void' is not assignable to type '(...args: unknown[]) => void'. Types of parameters 'errors' and 'args' are incompatible. Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>'.

When I do like this in Parent.vue:

```
const setFormErrors = (errors: ValidationErrorsType) => {
    formErrors.value = errors
}
```

error is gone. Is it possible to set types correctly for Vue3 dynamic components?

Comment: What is the difference between the 'error' code and the 'no-error' code ?

Comment: Attempted to reproduce this in Vue's playground but couldn't encounter the error. Also, it's worth noting that you need to ensure you're importing the ValidationErrorsType in both parent and child components.

Check out the [playground reproduction](https://shorturl.at/ghvZ5).

Comment: It seems like you solved your own issue, is that correct? And did you accidentally put the fixed code in the parent code section where you describe the problem?